# Javascript hexadecimal to binary using UTF8

Tags: php, javascript, character-encoding

I have data stored in an `SQLite` database as `BINARY(16)`, the value of which is determined by `PHP`'s [`hex2bin`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) function on a 32-character hexadecimal string.

As an example, the string `434e405b823445c09cb6c359fb1b7918` returns `CN@[4EÀ¶ÃYûy`.

The data stored in this database needs to be manipulated by `JavaScript`, and to do so I've used the following function (adapted from [Andris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217076/andris)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7695514/215384)):

```
// Convert hexadecimal to binary string
String.prototype.hex2bin = function ()
{

    // Define the variables
    var i = 0, l = this.length - 1, bytes = []

    // Iterate over the nibbles and convert to binary string
    for (i; i < l; i += 2)
    {
        bytes.push(parseInt(this.substr(i, 2), 16))
    }

    // Return the binary string
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, bytes)

}
```

This works as expected, returning `CN@[4EÀ¶ÃYûy` from `434e405b823445c09cb6c359fb1b7918`.

The problem I have, however, is that when dealing directly with the data returned by `PHP`'s `hex2bin` function I am given the string `CN@[�4E����Y�y` rather than `CN@[4EÀ¶ÃYûy`. This is making it impossible for me to work between the two (for context, `JavaScript` is being used to power an offline iPad app that works with data retrieved from a `PHP` web app) as I need to be able to use `JavaScript` to generate a 32-character hexadecimal string, convert it to a binary string, and have it work with `PHP`'s `hex2bin` function (and `SQLite`'s [`HEX`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#hex) function).

This issue, I believe, is that `JavaScript` uses `UTF-16` whereas the binary string is stored as `utf8_unicode_ci`. My initial thought, then, was that I need to convert the string to `UTF-8`. Using a Google search led me to [here](http://ecmanaut.blogspot.co.uk/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html) and searching StackOverflow led me to [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993893/215384), both of which recommend using `unescape(encodeURIComponent(str))`. However, this does return what I need (`CN@[�4E����Y�y`):

```
// CN@[Â4EÃÂÂ¶ÃYÃ»y
unescape(encodeURIComponent('434e405b823445c09cb6c359fb1b7918'.hex2bin()))
```

My question, then, is:

**How can I use `JavaScript` to convert a hexadecimal string into a `UTF-8` binary string?**

Comment: "*when dealing directly with the data returned by PHP's `hex2bin` function I am given the string `CN@[�4E����Y�y` rather than `CN@[4EÀ¶ÃYûy`*" - that sounds more like an encoding problem. How do you pass the data from PHP to JS?

Comment: It's pulled out of an SQLite database.

Comment: If that data is representing characters, why is it `BINARY(16)`? If the data is not representing characters, why are you trying to convert it to characters?

Comment: I'm storing a UUID as `BINARY(16)` in the database. This needs to be generated, retrieved, and used by both `PHP` and `JavaScript`. I'm using `SQLite`'s `HEX` function to get the hexadecimal string when selecting the `UUID`. The problem is when using `HEX(uuid)` on a UUID generated by the `hex2bin` `JavaScript` function above it differs from the actual hexadecimal string that was generated (whereas `PHP`'s `hex2bin` function works fine).

Comment: @MichaelRushton It would be much simpler to use `CHAR(32)` rather than `BINARY(16)`, you would already have hex digits everywhere and wouldn't have to worry about different conversions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10951183/215384

Comment: Still, why cannot you just convert to binary just-in-time when you are inserting and convert to hex as soon as you are querying? In fact, that's exactly what is advised in the answer you linked...

Comment: I'm converting to hex when retrieving (using `HEX`). Unfortunately, `SQLite` doesn't have an `UNHEX` function to do the reverse (unlike `MySQL`, which does).

Comment: @MichaelRushton but it supports blob literals.. so all you need is `X` in front of a quoted hex string. Replace `UNHEX('434e405b823445c09cb6c359fb1b7918')` with `X'434e405b823445c09cb6c359fb1b7918'`

Comment: Huh. That is exactly what I need. Means I don't have to use `JavaScript` to generate the binary string at all. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your applications don't have to handle binary at any point. Insertion is latest possible point and that's where you 
convert to binary at last. Selection is earliest possible point and that's where you convert to hex, and use
hex-strings in application throughout.

When inserting, you can replace `UNHEX` with blob literals:

```
INSERT INTO table (id)
VALUES (X'434e405b823445c09cb6c359fb1b7918')
```

When selection, you can `HEX`:

```
SELECT HEX(id) FROM table
```

Comment: Perfect. +1 and accepted. It might not answer the question as worded but it does solve the problem as explained.

Comment: @MichaelRushton it's not really a small task to explain the difference between PHP "strings" and strings in pretty much any other language like Javascript so I am glad to have avoided it :P

Comment: One follow up question: can this work with prepared statements? I've tried `(x?)` but that results in an error (as I was half expecting).

Comment: Also tried concatenating `(x || ?)` and that doesn't work either.

Comment: @MichaelRushton You have to concatenate it directly into the query, it doesn't seem PDO or mysqli support binary data directly in prepared statement binding.

Comment: Ah, OK, although it's SQLite using Titanium Studio's Database module -- but I guess it's the same (the PHP web app is fine as I can bind the result from `hex2bin`).

Answer (score 2):

Given a hex-encoded UTF-8 string, `hex',

```
hex.replace(/../g, '%$&')
```

will produce a URI-encoded UTF-8 string.

`decodeURIComponent` converts URI-encoded UTF-8 sequences into JavaScript UTF-16 encoded strings, so

```
decodeURIComponent(hex.replace(/../g, '%$&'))
```

should decode a properly hex-encoded UTF-8 string.

You can see that it works by applying it to the example from the `hex2bin` documentation.

```
alert(decodeURIComponent('6578616d706c65206865782064617461'.replace(/../g, '%$&')));
// alerts "example hex data"
```

---

The string you gave is not UTF-8 encoded though.  Specifically,

```
434e405b823445c09cb6c359fb1b7918
        ^
```

82 must follow a byte with at least the first two bits set, and 5b is not such a byte.

[RFC 2279](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2279.txt) explains:

> The table below summarizes the format of these different octet types.
>   The letter x indicates bits available for encoding bits of the UCS-4
>   character value.
>
> ```
> UCS-4 range (hex.)           UTF-8 octet sequence (binary)
> 0000 0000-0000 007F   0xxxxxxx
> 0000 0080-0000 07FF   110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
> 0000 0800-0000 FFFF   1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
> ```

Comment: The problem is in *generating* that UTF-8 byte string (in `JavaScript`) rather than *retrieving* it (from `PHP`/`SQLite`). Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @MichaelRushton, I'm still unclear.  Given a regular (UTF-16 encoded) JS string, you want to get the hex-encoded string, or get a UTF-8 octet string?

Comment: I need to store a hexadecimal string as `BINARY`. This binary string needs to be generated by both `PHP` and `JavaScript`. The problem is that the binary string returned by `PHP`'s `hex2bin` function is different to the binary string returned by the custom `JavaScript` `hex2bin` function above, despite the hexadecimal string being the same. I know that the `JavaScript` function is correct as the visual characters it returns are the same as those in the database -- it's just that when pulled out of the database the browser shows *different* characters (presumably as its a different encoding).

Comment: @MichaelRushton, please see my rewrite.

Comment: The hexadecimal string was generated by the code in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/215384

Comment: @MichaelRushton, that answer produces random byte-sequences.  Where does UTF-8 enter into this?

Comment: It was my *assumption* that `JavaScript` using `UTF-16` encoding and my `PHP` app using `UTF-8` encoding was the reason behind the inconsistency between the output of the `hex2bin` functions on the same hexadecimal string. I thought that if I could get `JavaScript` to use `UTF-8` then the binary string results would match.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Mike's answer, here's some code for encoding and decoding.

Note that the `escape/unescape()` functions are deprecated. If you need polyfills for them, you can check out the more comprehensive UTF-8 encoding example found here: http://jsfiddle.net/47zwb41o

```
// UTF-8 to hex
var utf8ToHex = function( s ){
    s = unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) );
    var chr, i = 0, l = s.length, out = '';
    for( ; i < l; i++ ){
        chr = s.charCodeAt( i ).toString( 16 );
        out += ( chr.length % 2 == 0 ) ? chr : '0' + chr;
    }
    return out;
};

// Hex to UTF-8
var hexToUtf8 = function( s ){
    return decodeURIComponent( s.replace( /../g, '%$&' ) );
};
```