# Deprecation of Javascript function unescape()

Tags: javascript

According to [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) the unescape() JavaScript function has been deprecated.
The site states,

> "The unescape() function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. Use
>   decodeURI() or decodeURIComponent() instead."

Should I go through and replace all instances of unescape()?

Is the deprecation of JavaScript functions something that web developers concern themselves with and actively update their JavaScript code?

or can I expect that most browsers will support JavaScript 1.5 in the foreseeable future?

Comment: Avoid using it in future, replace it if you see it, but otherwise don't panic.

Comment: First W3 School is not good resource to study, try [MDN] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Comment: I recommend to read MDN instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) is another resource as you're sure to draw fire for using W3Schools. If you decide to change it out, make sure you also change `escape()` to `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()` as appropriate throughout your code...

Comment: @WilfredoP But is it not correct here?

Comment: *"Is the deprecation of JavaScript functions something that web developers concern themselves with and actively update their JavaScript code?"* I guess many don't, but they should! Having to do deal with so much legacy stuff is a big pain point in web development.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek see this http://www.w3fools.com/ and that's Why is not good resource.

Comment: MDN in this case has scant information on the reason for preferring the newer functions. As far as I can tell it has to do with IETF URI syntax updates, particularly around the treatment of UTF-8 code sequences.

Comment: @WilfredoP That site is *extremely* out-of-date, and W3 Schools have fixes many of the problems that the site used to state. It used to be bad, but today it's actually quite decent.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek it's not out-of-date anymore; they now acknowledge that W3Schools is "decent", which is what I'd say too.

Comment: @Pointy Your right, I guess I mean the premises of the site is out-of-date, in the sense to warn users that w3schools is a bad (awful) site.

Comment: before jumping in to replace `unescape()` with some other flavour make sure you are getting the same output; the output of `escape()` and `encodeURI()` is not the same, and the same applies to `unescape()` and `decodeURI()`. For example the treatment of the `=` character is different.

Comment: DO NOT replace all instances. Both W3Schools and MDN are misleading, as `decodeURIComponent` does not the same thing.
Example: If you need to feed `btoa`this function would replace `unescape`:
`unescapeForbtoa = function(str) { return str.replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, (match, p1) => { return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);})}`. Use it like this `btoa(unescapeForbtoa(encodeURIComponent('é')))`

Comment: Check out this answer for implementation of escape and unescape functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77748224/3735576

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape you should update your old scripts:

> This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.

#### A Quick Fix?

Fixing it could be as simple as dropping a line into your JS to add in an `unescape()` method if one doesn't exist.

```
window.unescape = window.unescape || window.decodeURI;
```

Comment: So is there a way to check in code (i.e. conditional) if the JavaScript function is deprecated?

Comment: You can check if it exists: `var hasUnescape = (typeof window.unescape === "function");` but that's essentially what the quick-fix is doing - its defining the `unescape` method as itself (if it exists) else `decodeURI`.

Comment: The two functions are not the same! `unescape('%E9')` will return `é`, but `decodeURIComponent('%E9')` will throw `Malformed URI`

Comment: felixbecker- since you mentioned they're not the same, which will be the proper function to replace unescape with?

Comment: Check out this answer for implementation of escape and unescape functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77748224/3735576